# Atma(n) of human, animal, vegetal, mineral forms of existence

Tags: atma

Is Atma(n) the same, identically, in human, animal, vegetal, mineral forms of being, or is there a difference in grade, in degree between them? So to speak, if every species has its own form of intelligence (intelligence, not reason, rationality, which is characteristic to humans), and if every species has a degree or form of intelligence according to its nature (human, animal, vegetal, mineral), is the same for Atma(n)?

Comment: Multiple questions. 1) This has been previously answered. In non-living forms (minerals,etc.) it is only the Sat aspect that is present. 2) This has been previously answered. All living beings have their only jiva. Intelligence is not the atman. Intelligence is consciousness. How much consciousness a being manifests is dependent on the the size of its physical brain.